# Delete ALL table view rows that are generated with core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a table view (table view1) which is generated by core data `(entity1)`, I can delete the rows one by one, but I would like to delete the whole table with a button at once, how can I do that?

I have something to delete the whole deal, but the problem is that I have a second table view controller (table view2) which is also generated by core data `(entity2)` and when I want to delete the `"table view1"` I also delete the `"table view2"` and I just want to delete the "table view1" whose content is located on entity1..

The code I have, to delete the data is:

```
        NSURL *storeURL = [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] URLForPersistentStore:[[[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject]];
        // lock the current context
        [managedObjectContext lock];
        [managedObjectContext reset];//to drop pending changes
        //delete the store from the current managedObjectContext
        if ([[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:[[[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject] error:nil])
        {
            // remove the file containing the data
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
            //recreate the store like in the  appDelegate method
            [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:nil];//recreates the persistent store
        }
        [managedObjectContext unlock];
        //that's it !

        [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to fetch all objects of the entity and delete them:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ...; // your managed object context 
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity1"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // handle error
} else {
    for (NSManagedObject *object in objects) {
        [context deleteObject:object];
    }
    [context save:&error];
}
```